# Google chrome crashes in Windows 7 Enterprise Edition 64 bit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I open an Image gallery application in Google chrome 19 browser it crashes suddenly. It happens only when I view the actual resolution image. There is no problem in the case of thumbnail image. I have used the image pre-loading here. Actual size of the image is approx 800 KB. When I try to view the images side by side the browser crashes and doesn't respond also.I found that there is a general issue regarding chrome crashing in Windows 7 - 64 bit OS. There is no problem in the case of 32 bit Operating System.Can I get any work around for resolving this problem? Is it a browser related issue or Os related? I found that the memory usage is not higher,it is OK. Then what will be the real problem?

Comment: What's `javascript` issue here? Please do remove unnecessary tags.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to reinstall the browser by first uninstalling it and downloading it again to see if the problem persists. If it does, I recommend you to file a bug report with **Chrome**. I could not find your problem being reported under bugs files, but a lot of similar bug related issues have been noticed with Chrome. So please do the reinstall and check the issue.

**or are you using an unstable feature???** by using [flags]? does turning it off help? try looking into that first.